# WPF Using Multiple Threads to Display Loading Message

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've posted a similar question before, however now I am tailoring this question to a specific approach that I have decided to go with.

Simply put what I am trying to do is display a loading message after the user clicks on one page, that dissapears when the next page is fully loaded (loading 27000 companies into a DataGrid) and then the next page is displayed. The order looks like this;

1. User clicks on button on first page
2. "Please Wait...." is displayed on the same page whilst the next page
   is loading
3. Next page is fully loaded
4. Hide "Please Wait...."
5. Display next page

What was recommended to me was using `async` and `wait`. This however froze my UI and would not work (`Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`). I then started looking at using multiple threads which can hopefully solve my problem. This is what I have attempted so far;

**The user has clicked the button to the next page**

```
public CompanyManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        this.DataContext = new
        {
            ThreadId = thread.ManagedThreadId
        };
    }
```

**The Page's Loaded event is called;**

```
    private void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var wait = new PleaseWait("My title", "My Message", () => FillDataGrid());
            wait.ShowDialog();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
```

**FillDataGrid() is the method that takes all the time (retrieves the companies over OleDB), and looks like this;**

```
private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        var _cDS = new CompanyDataService();
        var Companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>();
        Companies = _cDS.HandleCompanySelect();
        CompanyICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Companies);
        //CompanyICollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("CompanyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        DataContext = this;
        cancelButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        if (compNameRad.IsChecked == false && 
            compTownRad.IsChecked == false && 
            compPcodeRad.IsChecked == false)
        {
            searchBox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
        SetDefaultFilter();
    }
```

This almost works in that the next page is loaded, the "Please Wait...." is displayed however I then get the error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. Am I using the thread functionality incorrectly?

**EDIT**: I should show `PleaseWait` too!

```
    public partial class PleaseWait : Window
    {
        readonly Action _action;
        public PleaseWait(string title, string message, Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = title;
            this.label.Content = message;
        }

        private async void loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => _action());
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: For StepUp;

```
    private void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            var wait = new PleaseWait("My title", "My Message", () => FillDataGrid());
            wait.ShowDialog();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }));
    }
```

Comment: You want to set the loading message on the main UI thread, load the data objects on a background thread, then pass the data objects back to the main UI thread and bind them to the UI, then remove loading message and update UI (also UI thread). The only thing that should be done on the background thread is loading the data objects. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8759160/302677) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930792/302677) for some examples and explanations

Answer (score 0):

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Typically, WPF applications start with two threads: one for handling
>   rendering and another for managing the UI. The rendering thread
>   effectively runs hidden in the background while the UI thread receives
>   input, handles events, paints the screen, and runs application code.
>   Most applications use a single UI thread, although in some situations
>   it is best to use several.

[Then MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The UI thread queues work items inside an object called a Dispatcher.
>   The Dispatcher selects work items on a priority basis and runs each
>   one to completion.  Every UI thread must have at least one Dispatcher,
>   and each Dispatcher can execute work items in exactly one thread.

And you are updating UI from non-UI thread, consequently you've caught an exception.

```
    private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        var _cDS = new CompanyDataService();
        var Companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>();
        Companies = _cDS.HandleCompanySelect();
        CompanyICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Companies);
        //CompanyICollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("CompanyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        DataContext = this;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            cancelButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            if (compNameRad.IsChecked == false &&  compTownRad.IsChecked == false &&
                compPcodeRad.IsChecked == false)
            {
                searchBox.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }));
        SetDefaultFilter();
    }
```

**Update:**
This code is not eligible:

```
private void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        var wait = new PleaseWait("My title", "My Message", () => FillDataGrid());
        wait.ShowDialog();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }));
}
```

as you are creating new thread inside of `PageLoaded`. It means that new thread is created in UI thread and updates UI from non-UI thread. That is, you are updating UI without `Dispatcher`. You should use `Dispatcher` inside of newly created `thread` to update `UI`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I need to use the `Thread` to display the message, not in `FillDataGrid()` method, maybe in the `PageLoaded` method?

Comment: Hmm I tried using it in the `PageLoaded` method but still had the same error.

Comment: I updated my answer with the updated code at the end

Comment: @CBreeze if it helps to you, it is possible to mark it as an answer to simplify search for other people.

Comment: @CBreeze feel free to ask any question.